# How to Install Skype for Linux in Ubuntu 16.04 Via Console only?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, skype, console

I use Ubuntu 16.04

I want to install **Skype for Linux** through the console.

Is it possible?

If I try to install via Software Installer, it closes automatically.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: The linked question doesn't address the installation of Skype Alpha.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thank you for catching the oversight. VTC retracted.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/804483/how-to-get-latest-skype-for-linux-version-from-repository

Answer (score 46, accepted):

## Skype for Linux

You can download Skype on official website. They have two versions: DEB and RPM. Link to download - [Skype for Linux](https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/)

### Install Skype for Linux on Debian/Ubuntu via console

1. Install `apt-transport-https`:

   ```
   sudo apt install apt-transport-https
   ```
2. Download key GPG key:

   ```
   curl https://repo.skype.com/data/SKYPE-GPG-KEY | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
3. Add Skype to the list of Apt repositories:

   ```
   echo "deb https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skypeforlinux.list
   ```
4. Install Skype for Linux:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install skypeforlinux
   ```

Comment: `apt-transport-https` shouldn't be needed anymore. The debian package page says "This is a dummy transitional package - https support has been moved into the apt package in 1.5. It can be safely removed." Still, that command is harmless and the rest was exactly what I was looking for. +1

Comment: @Dantes I just performed these steps and all went well until I got '~$ sudo apt install skypeforlinux
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package skypeforlinux'

Comment: This approach works fine and it skype is working. Only issue is that in Ubuntu 18.04 a launcher icon is not being created. Can you suggest a fix for it? Thanks!