# Skype repository not deleted on package purge

Tags: 14.04, skype, repository

When installing Skype from the [linux repository](https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/) a repository `skype-stable` is added as noted in answers to [How to get latest Skype for Linux version from repository?](https://askubuntu.com/a/804498/109883).

However, when the package is purged the repository is still left in place and active.

Comment: The information of the repositories that the `apt-get` uses is located in the `/etc/apt/sources.list`  file and the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` folder. If you remove/purge a package, the repository may remain in the configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with other answers that you are right. When installing the package, the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list` and a public key are added, but they are not removed when purging.

It would be fully possible to add a maintenance script to the package which removes those things when purging. If you install e.g. Google Chrome, and purge it later, the apt sources entry is automatically removed.

The absence of such a script in the `skypeforlinux` package is a bug IMO, which someone may want to report to Skype.

Comment: Also, if you remove the repo, don't forget to remove the repository keys (using the `apt-key list` and `apt-key del <KEYID>` commands).

Answer (score 4):

As you said, you can't remove this repository with purging or removing `skypeforlinux` package.

You should remove that repository file manually.

---

Skype make its repository's file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory with `skype-stable.list` name.

So you should comment all lines of this file with this command:

```
sudo sed -i 's/^/#/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list
```

And then run this command to apply changes in your repositories:

```
sudo apt update
```

---

Also you can remove that file completely with this command, but the above way (comment all lines) is much safer than it:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  Purging a package does not remove the repository entry.  You need to do that manually.  One way is to edit the repository list `/etc/apt/sources.list` (use your favorite text editor, but you'll need to have root privilege) and comment or delete the line that includes `skype-stable`.

There's more information [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiir5HE04HWAhVH6IMKHdS7CPkQFggoMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Faskubuntu.com%2Fquestions%2F307%2Fhow-can-ppas-be-removed&usg=AFQjCNG729WpdNkEsn8Six5stgn1z2v5mg), including how to look at your repository list and a direct method to edit it.