# How do you upgrade Skype to the latest version?

Tags: upgrade, update-manager, skype, versions

My Skype does not automatically upgrade to the latest version and it is not obvious how to upgrade it. Can someone explain how to do this?

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and my Skype version is 8.56.0.103.

This screenshot shows that there is an update available:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get latest Skype for Linux version from repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/804483/how-to-get-latest-skype-for-linux-version-from-repository)

Comment: Welcome to this community! For all I know, since recently, there are two ways to get Skype in Ubuntu: one is the deb file from Skype itself, and the other is from the Ubuntu Software Centre, which has an own package management dubbed 'snap'. The latter guarantees updates. For the first one, you might have to inform your package management system, apt, where to look for updates. I cannot answer this question, perhaps other will. My two cents, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be in the same situation as me. I had `skypeforlinux` installed from `https://repo.skype.com`, but in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/skypeforlinx.list` it said:

```
# deb https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
```

and in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list` it said:

```
# deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
```

So it looks like the repo has been disabled during the latest distribution upgrade. I probably haven't been getting updates since then. I may or may not have been shown a notification at the time, and clicked straight past it. Following the instructions in [the thread linked by @karel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/804483/how-to-get-latest-skype-for-linux-version-from-repository) worked for me. (Purge the existing installation, download the deb file, install with dpkg.) The comment hash has been removed from skype-stable.list and I now have version 8.58.0.93.

This has triggered me to have a closer look at my apt sources, and it turns out there's a few things in there that need cleaning out.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Skype by adding the Skype PPA, it should automatically update (mine does, every few weeks, usually).  If yours isn't automatically updating, and your Ubuntu in general is, there may be a problem with your PPA entry (that has occurred since you installed).  The alternative situation is that you may have Skype installed by some other method -- by tarball, for instance, or by downloading a .deb file and manually installing it.

If the latter case applies, I'd suggest you go to the Skype home page and follow their instructions for enabling the Skype PPA and install the current version from there. Once that's done, Skype will update whenever there's a new version available from Microsoft.